# I am using selectpicker I want to edit the data coming from the database, but all options are coming already selected

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-selectpicker

[all categories coming selected which i want to see only which information is coming from database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDxY0.png)
sorry for my english.

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <label>Categories</label>
    <!-- SEARCH JS find (selectpicker) -->
  <select name="product_cat" id="product_cat" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
    <?php 

    while($productcatcek=$productcatsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    ?>
    
      <option selected="">
        <dl>
          <dt ><?php
          if ($productcatcek['pcat_id']==$productcatcek['pcat_id']) {
             echo $productcatcek['pcat_name'];
           } 
          ?> - </dt>
          <dd <?php echo $productcatcek['pcat_id']==$productcatcek['pcat_id'] ? 'selected=""' : '' ?>><?php echo $productcatcek['spcat_name']; ?></dd>
        </dl>
      </option>
    
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <!-- SEARCH Finish -->
</div>
```

**SOLUTION**

```
<option value="<?php echo $productcatcek['spcat_id']; ?>" <?php echo $productcatcek['spcat_id']==$productcek['product_cat'] ? 'selected=""' : '' ?>>
  <dl>
   <dt><?php echo $productcatcek['pcat_name']; ?> - </dt>
   <dd><?php echo $productcatcek['spcat_name']; ?></dd>
  </dl>
 </option>
```

Comment: Just `'selected'` - as in `<option selected>`

Comment: That code which outputs `selected` dynamically needs to be moved from `<dd>` to `<option>`.

Comment: <option <?php echo $productcatcek['spcat_id']==$productcek['product_cat'] ? 'selected=""' : '' ?>>
                            <dl>
                              <dt><?php echo $productcatcek['pcat_name']; ?> - </dt>
                              <dd><?php echo $productcatcek['spcat_name']; ?></dd>
                            </dl>
                          </option>

Answer (score 0):

The `selected` attribute only needs to exist on your `<option>` element; it doesn't need to have a value. To not have an `<option>` selected, simply don't include the attribute

Comment: If you check the image I added, It will explain it fully. my all categories coming selected. i just want to see only which category added on my mysql database.

Comment: I tried this :: <?php echo $productcek['product_cat']==$productcek['spcat_id'] ? 'selected=""' : ''; ?>

and this :: <?php if ($productcatcek['spcat_id']==$productcatcek['product_cat']) {echo $productcek['spcat_name']; }  ?>

Comment: The code `$productcatcek['pcat_id']==$productcatcek['pcat_id'] ? 'selected=""' : ''` is always going to return `true`, because you're comparing the string to itself, so the `selected` attribute is always going to be present